# Manual slide-in animation using delta time

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a simple slide-in animation for my game. The box is shown at the bottom with character dialog.

The animation is supposed to look as follows:

A square slides in from the left, then waits a bit, then expands to its full width.

The box is made using Unity's GUI Box. The timing is extended for debugging purposes (I need to be able to clearly see the animation). Everything works the way I want it to, except when it initially animates from the square to the rectangle, it appears to "jump" instead of transitioning relatively smoothly like the rest of the animation.

[image]

Am I doing something improperly? I know it isn't coded spectacularly (I wrote it in 5 minutes in the first way that occurred to me), but I'm pretty sure my logic is correct. Maybe my timer is causing problems?

```
private string boxString = "Hello, world! I am sample character dialog.";

private float elapsedTime = 0.0f;

private float initialSlideInDuration = 1.333f;
private float waitBetweenSlideAndExpand = 0.666f;
private float expansionDuration;

private float boxHeightPercentage = 0.10f;
private float boxWidthPercentage = 0.95f;
private float positionFromLeft;
private float positionFromBottom;
private float boxWidth;
private float boxHeight;

// instantiate variables before any frames are drawn
void Start () {
    expansionDuration = initialSlideInDuration + waitBetweenSlideAndExpand + 3.333f;
    boxWidth = Screen.width*boxWidthPercentage;
    boxHeight = Screen.height*boxHeightPercentage;
    positionFromLeft = (Screen.width - (Screen.width * boxWidthPercentage)) / 2;
    positionFromBottom = Screen.height - (positionFromLeft + boxHeight);
}

// called once per frame
void Update () {
    elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;  
}

// render and handle GUI events
void OnGUI() {
    // slide in square
    if (elapsedTime <= initialSlideInDuration) {
        float initialLeftPadding = -positionFromLeft - boxHeight;
        float finalLeftPadding = positionFromLeft;
        float movementDistance = (2 * positionFromLeft) + boxHeight;
        float progress = elapsedTime / initialSlideInDuration;

        GUI.Box (new Rect ((progress * movementDistance) + initialLeftPadding, positionFromBottom, boxHeight, boxHeight), boxString);
    } 
    // if square is ready and we have waited, animate to rectangle
    else if (elapsedTime > initialSlideInDuration+waitBetweenSlideAndExpand && elapsedTime <= expansionDuration) {
        float initialWidth = boxHeight;
        float finalWidth = boxWidth;
        float growth = finalWidth - initialWidth;
        float progress = elapsedTime / expansionDuration;

        GUI.Box(new Rect(positionFromLeft, positionFromBottom, (progress * growth) + initialWidth, boxHeight), boxString);
    }
    // stay as full width rectangle
    else if(elapsedTime > expansionDuration){
        GUI.Box (new Rect (positionFromLeft, positionFromBottom, boxWidth, boxHeight), boxString);
    }
    // we are waiting, display the square with left padding
    else {
        GUI.Box (new Rect (positionFromLeft, positionFromBottom, boxHeight, boxHeight), boxString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to be frame-rate independent you should use a coroutine that's how i'd do it :

```
float startWidth = 1f;
float endWidth = 10f;
float startPosition = 1f;
float endPosition = 10f;
float positionX, widthX;

IEnumerator SlideInAnimation(float slideTime = 0.3f, float expandTime = 1f) {
    float t = slideTime;
    while (t>0) {
        positionX = Mathf.Lerp(startPosition,endPosition,1-(t/slideTime));
        t-=Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null; //Wait for end of Frame (almost)
    }
    positionX = endPosition;

    t = expandTime;
    while (t>0) {
        widthX = Mathf.Lerp(startWidth,endWidth,1-(t/expandTime));
        t-=Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null; //Wait for end of Frame (almost)
    }
    widthX = endWidth;
}

void OnGUI() {
    GUI.Box (new Rect (positionX , positionFromBottom, widthX , boxHeight), boxString);
}
```

and you run that this way :

```
IEnumerator Start() {
    positionX = startPosition;
    widthX = startWidth;

    yield return StartCoroutine(SlideInAnimation());
    //All stuff happening after that line will be run when the animation finishes
}
```

Here is what happened here :

I got rid of OnGUI, because you want something which happens over time and the delta time of GUI calls is unpredictable. Good thing is you are only handling animation here and not logic so you just need stuff to happen once per frame, (no need to move stuff twice before render).

Good solution for that is to create a coroutine to handle all that

Comment: Also as a side note, OldGui in unity is getting deprecated (and it's ugly ugly ugly, smart, but ugly...), you'll probably be better off concentrating on learning the new UI which came out with Unity 5. If you are dependant on the old GUI for a project which needs to be maintained, then way to go :D (but i wish you good luck...)

Comment: Very nice solution. Had to read up on `yield`, I'd never seen that used practically. Just one question, what is the equivalent in Unity 5? I just checked their docs for the new UI and it doesn't seem like they have something like `GUI.Box`. What did you have in mind?

Comment: To do the equivalent of a GUI box in the new UI, you'd have a "Panel" with a "Text" as a child of that panel, and typically you would change the Transform of the panel

Answer (score 1):

You can consider use simple and really helpfull asset from AssetStore - [LeanTween](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/3595). I have similar problems with GUI animations and that simple thing makes my work easier.

Answer (score 0):

Update Function is called every frame, Regardless of everyone else running.

Everyone else that is running, is considered by the Compiler or on Runtime as different Execution.

The Problem in your code is The Update is getting ahead of the `elapsedTime` Calculation, Leaving the logic inside your OnGUI be updated to the `elapsedTime` Value.

All you have to do is Remove the Update() function and move the `elapsedTime` Increment inside OnGUI.

```
void Update () {
    elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;  
}
```

Comment: -1: you should not rely on `Time.deltaTime` from inside `OnGUI` since `OnGUI` can be called multiple times per frame and `deltaTime` would hold the same value each call, until next frame where it would be updated again

Comment: Lol, my answer is based on your question. I would not give you any other answers as for StockOver flow Standards, what you have in your code is what we are going to base our answers from. EVEN if there is a better way to do it, because it may not be what you're looking for. FYI.